# Get ip range from specific ip address using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I Encounter a problem while writing  python program for ip address. 
Program is :-

```
ip1='192.168.0.0'
ip2='192.168.255.255'
ip1=ip1.split('.')
ip2=ip2.split('.')
while ip1[2]<=ip2[2]:
    print ip1[0]+'.'+ip1[1]+'.'+ip1[2]+'.'+ip1[3]
    ip1[2]=ip1[2]+1
while ip1[3]<=ip2[3]:
    print ip1[0]+'.'+ip1[1]+'.'+ip1[2]+'.'+ip1[3]
    ip1[3]=ip1[3]+1
```

This program is gives me only one result :- 192.168.0.0
Expected Ans is :-

```
    192.168.0.0
    192.168.0.1
    192.168.0.2
    ......
    192.168.255.255
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ipaddress` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)) module builtin within Python:

```
import ipaddress

for address in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.0.0/16'):
    print(address)
```

Prints:

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3

...all the way to:

192.168.255.252
192.168.255.253
192.168.255.254
192.168.255.255
```

Comment: i didn't know there is library for that, expected nothing less from python :)

Answer (score 1):

just use like this.

```
for i in range(256):
    for j in range(256):
        ip = "192.168.%d.%d" % (i, j)
        print ip
```

output:

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
.
.
192.168.255.254
192.168.255.255
```

Answer (score 0):

use ipaddress module. you can check ip range easily. (range from nip1 to nip2)

```
import ipaddress

ip1='192.168.0.0'
ip2='192.168.255.255'


nip1 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip1))
nip2 = int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip2))

for n in range(nip1, nip2+1):
    add=str(ipaddress.IPv4Address(n))
    print(add)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your range of IP addresses to be dynamic, you can do the following:

```
ip1='192.168.0.0'
ip2='192.168.255.255'

first, second, thirdStart, lastStart = list(map(int,ip1.split(".")))
thirdEnd, lastEnd = list(map(int,ip2.split(".")))[2:] 

for i in range(thirdStart,thirdEnd+1,1):
    for j in range(lastStart,lastEnd+1,1):
        print(".".join(list(map(str,[first,second,i,j]))))
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.0
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
192.168.0.6
.
.
.
192.168.255.252
192.168.255.253
192.168.255.254
192.168.255.255
```